# My 'randomString' function keeps returning the same result

Tags: random, lua

randomString.lua

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- File: randomString.lua
-- Author: Don Draper
-- 
-- This is the Lua implementation of my simple 'randomString' function
-- which I previous wrote in PAWN.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

randomString = {}

local randomCharset = {
    "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
    "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
}

function randomString.generate(length)
    local currentString = ""
    for index = 1, length do
        currentString = currentString .. randomCharset[math.random(1, #randomCharset)]
    end
    return currentString
end
```

Test.lua

```
require("randomString")

print(randomString.generate(16))
io.read()
```

So here is my 'randomString' function which I originally wrote in the PAWN programming language, I thought I would implement it to Lua to generate some password salts. However whenever I call my ported function it always returns the same output whenever I first run the program.

Take this piece of code for example.

```
for i = 0, 100 do
    print(randomString.generate(16))
end
```

It will always generate the same list of random strings. Can anyone please explain why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use such code (even with `math.randomseed`) for security purposes. `math.random` isn't cryptographically secure.

Comment: @CodesInChaos how would you go about generating random strings for password salts? I will be using it with SHA256.

Comment: You will need access to the secure random numbers your operating system provides to you. On windows this means a wrapper for `CryptGenRandom`, for linux it means reading from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: You shouldn't use SHA256 as a password hash either. You need to use a specialized slow password hash like PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt. See [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) on security.SE for details. I recommend writing the whole password hash (salt and all) in c, and then exposing it to lua. Given the performance requirements (implementation must be fast to allow an expensive hash) and the lack of secure RNG, you probably won't be able to produce a good lua implementation.

Comment: My knowledge of C is awful I would never be able to write a password hashing system. Back when I programmed in PAWN, I used Whirlpool to hash the passwords with a salt using my function above (in PAWN obviously). I failed to find a Whirlpool hashing function for Lua, so I looked for the next best thing IMO, which was SHA512 or SHA256, and I came across a SHA2 library for Lua, which is found in the link  below.

https://github.com/JustAPerson/LuaCrypt

I am just so surprised some people use MD5 to hash their passwords.

Comment: Single iteration SHA-2 is almost as bad as MD5. Both can only be broken with brute-force, so the only practical difference is that MD5 is slightly cheaper to compute. A proper password hash iterates SHA-2 over 10'000 times (and even that is very low, in most cases 100'000 is more appropriate. It's doubtful that you can afford such an iteration count with a lua implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`math.random` generates a sequence of **pseudorandom** numbers, that is a deterministic sequence that will resemble an actual random sequence. The sequence generated by `math.random` will be always the same, unless you use [`math.randomseed`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.randomseed).

For every possible value with which you call `math.randomseed`, `math.random` will generate a different pseudorandom sequence.

Try this, for example, and you will see a different sequence:

```
math.randomseed( 7654321 )
for i = 0, 100 do
    print(randomString.generate(16))
end
```

If you want a truly random sequence you should feed `randomseed` with a true random number before starting the generation.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but even then the result will not be a sequence of truly random numbers. It will be a pseudo random sequence selected by a seed derived from a truly random number. The difference is small, but still significant for some uses. If the sequence were to be used to key a stream cipher, for instance, then a weak pseudo random sequence could make the whole cryptosystem weak no matter how well you chose the seed.

Comment: @RBerteig Yep! You're right! And given the context of the OP's question, it is not nitpicking at all. Thanks for this clarification! It is worth mentioning that Lua built-in random generator is not a cryptographic-strength generator, so it is not to be used for applications where security is paramount.