# Lua 5.2.1 - Random Numbers

Tags: random, lua, numbers

In Lua 5.2.1, I tried to generate a random number with

```
num = math.random(9)
```

However, every time I run my program:

```
num = math.random(9)
print("The generated number is "..num..".")
```

I get the same number.

```
brendan@osiris:~$ lua number 
The generated number is 8.
brendan@osiris:~$ lua number 
The generated number is 8.
brendan@osiris:~$ lua number 
The generated number is 8.
```

This is frustrating, because everytime I try to generate a new number and restart the program, I get the same sequence.

Is there a different way of generating a number?

Also, I've looked into

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

but I don't really get it. If this is indeed the solution could you explain how it works, what it does, and what number I'd get?

Thx,

- Brendan

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937897/my-randomstring-function-keeps-returning-the-same-result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not particular to Lua. Pseudorandom generators usually work like that: they need a *seed* to start and the sequence they generate is not really random, but actually deterministic given a seed. This is a good thing for debugging but for production you need to alter the seed in a "random" way. An easy and typical way of doing that is to use the time to set the seed *once* at the start of the program.

Answer (score 2):

In Lua this is the expected output. You are not guranteed to get different sequences across different sessions.

However, any subsequent calls to `math.random` will generate a new number:

```
>> lua
> =math.random(9)
1

>> lua
> =math.random(9)
1

>> lua
> =math.random(9)
1
> =math.random(9)
6
> =math.random(9)
2
```

`math.randomseed()` will change which sequence is replayed. If you set `math.randomseed(3)` for example, you will always get the same sequence, just like above:

```
>> lua
> math.randomseed(3)
> =math.random(9)
1
> =math.random(9)
2
> =math.random(9)
3

>> lua
> math.randomseed(3)
> =math.random(9)
1
> =math.random(9)
2
> =math.random(9)
3
```

If you however set `math.randomseed()` to a unique value each run, for example os.time(), you will ofcourse get an unique sequence each time.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to call 'math.randomseed()'

'Why?'

Because Lua generates pseudo random numbers.

--One of the best seeds for 'math.randomseed()' is the time.

So, you'll first write:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
```

After this,

```
num = math.random(9)
print("The generated number is "..num..".")
```

However, there is a bug on Windows. Then if you just write 'num = math.random(9)' the generated number will be the same for 1 hour, i think.

'So how can I resolve this?'

It's easy, you need to do a for loop.

```
for n = 0, 5 do
    num = math.random(9)
end
```

So, in Windows, the final code would be:

```
math.randomseed(os.time())

for n = 0, 5 do
    num = math.random(9)
end

print("The generated number is "..num..".")
```

OBS: If 'for n = 0, 5 do' does not work perfectly, then replace 5 with 10.